# how to load one div into another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a menu in which upon clicking a number of navigation div's, different content will load from a separate HTML page into a single container div on the main page. I would like to incorporate .fadeIn and .fadeOut in order that the content cross-fades rather than just switching out.

Here is the script I have written just to load content from two navigation divs:

```
$(function() { 
$(".navIcon1") .click(function(){
    $("#container").load("content.html #div1");

$(".navIcon2") .click(function(){
    $("#container").load("content.html #div2");
});
});
});
```

As I am new to working with jQuery, I am uncertain how to create a variable in order to include the .fadeIn and the .fadeOut to what I currently have working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hide container first then after page load fadeIn it.

```
$("#container").hide().load("content.html #div1", function(){
    $("#container").fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Deferred objects can play a key role here:

```
var req = $.get("content.html");

$("#container").fadeOut("1000",function(){
    req.done(function(html){
        $("#container").html(
            // $.parseHTML prevents a memory leak
            $($.parseHTML(html)).find("#div1").addBack().filter("#div1");
        ).fadeIn("1000");
    });
});
```

This would allow you to retrieve the content as fast as possible while still having a fadeOut and fadeIn animation.